# How to Convert Dictionary<string, dynamic> to Dictionary<string, uint>?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I'm learning C# & have below code.

```
private static Policy ConstructNode(Policy policy, Dictionary<string, dynamic> noticeDictionary)
    {
        Policy policy = new Policy();

        foreach (var pair in noticeDictionary)
        {
        policy.Emails = pair.Value; // HERE, I GET RUNTIME ERROR
        ...
        }
    return policy;
 }
```

The `Emails` in `Policy` class is of type `Dictionary<string, uint>` & `pair.Value` contains `Dictionary<string, dynamic>`

Noticedictionary is as shown below:

```
noticeDictionary.Add("Notice", JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(val));
```

The val contains JSON string which can contain either string or int values with string keys.

How do I cast them so it won't give error?

Comment: We need to see the code that creates the `Dictionary<string, dynamic>` no way to know the type of dynamic... that is the problem with dynamic.

Comment: Your description of the class structure doesn't even fit well with your code. If `Emails` is a dictionary, why are you assigning `pair.Value` to it? Unless `pair.Value` is *itself* a dictionary, this would never work. Also, you're doing this in a loop, why? Every loop iteration is just overwriting the previous value that was set. I think you need to revisit this (and get rid of `dynamic` while you're in there).

Comment: You may have good reason for using it, but since you say you're learning, you should do your best to avoid `dynamic` at all when you can

Comment: I'd just like to emphasize @BenAaronson's advice.  There is very likely no reason for you to be using `dynamic`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dictionary<string, uint> Converted =  noticeDictionary
    // Next steps converts to an IEnumerable<anonymoustype<string,uint>>
    .Select(kvp=> new { key = kvp.Key , val = (uint)kvp.Value})
    // Now that we have strongly typed data in enumerable form, get it back into a dictionary
    .ToDictionary(item=>item.Key,item=>item.Value);
```

About your secondary question (if the type is mixed how do i cast for no error), that's not possible, but if the strings are just encoded uint you could handle both by modifying the select val as such

```
    .Select(kvp=> new { key = kvp.Key , val = (kvp.Value is int) ? (kvp.Value) : uint.Parse((string)kvp.Value)}) // This is untested, let me know if you have trouble
```